# Setting up LWM2M device communicates with IDAS

Tags: fiware, lwm2m

I am new to Fiware and need help.

I want to configure a road side device (sensor) using CoAP protocol to the IDAS IoT agent (Lightweight M2M agent), so this device can send some data to IDAS.

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

We are a company that works with LwM2M protocol through FIWARE technologies, may be our IoT FIWARE Dockerized infrastructure could help you.

https://gitlab.hopu.eu/software/FIWARE/fiware-docker-infrastructure

Comment: Hi @German Molina,

Not sure how your infrastructure could help me, but here is the scenario at hand. I want the lwm2m client to register with the fiware iot agent, (later, the client should send update to iot agent). Then get context update info from orion.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments before, I understand that you want to build an scenario in order to connect your sensors to IotAgent-LWM2M.

#### In order to use LW2M2 IotAgent:

1. Install LW2M2 agent: git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/lightweightm2m-iotagent.git
2. Install yarm to install all dependencies using npm packages
3. Install Lightweight M2M client: git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/lwm2m-node-lib.git

#### Technical Requirements:

1. Mosquito MQTT v3.1 Broker
2. Orion latest
3. MongoDB v.3.2
4. NodeJS v0.12

I suggest you to use docker to install dependencies before comment

```
 version : "2"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    command: --nojournal
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    expose:
      - "27017"
  orion:
    image: fiware/orion
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "1026:1026"
    command: -dbhost mongo
    expose:
      - "1026"
  mosquitto:
    image: ansi/mosquitto
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
    expose:
      - "1883"
```

Note:
**Mosquitto play a role like a sensor**

### Getting started: StepByStep

#### Step 1 : Create a device

```
(curl localhost:4041/iot/devices -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'fiware-service: Factory' --header      'fiware-servicepath: /robots' \
-d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
"devices": [
   {
    "device_id": "robot1",
    "entity_type": "Robot",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "name": "Battery",
        "type": "number"
      }
    ],
    "lazy": [
      {
        "name": "Message",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "commands": [
      {
        "name": "Position",
        "type": "location"
      }
    ],
  "internal_attributes": {
    "lwm2mResourceMapping": {
      "Battery" : {
        "objectType": 7392,
        "objectInstance": 0,
        "objectResource": 1
      },
      "Message" : {
        "objectType": 7392,
        "objectInstance": 0,
        "objectResource": 2
      },
      "Position" : {
        "objectType": 7392,
        "objectInstance": 0,
        "objectResource": 3
      }
    }
  }
}]}
EOF
```

#### Step 2 : Create a service

```
curl -X POST -H "Fiware-Service: myHome" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /environment" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
"services": [
{
      "resource": "/",
      "apikey": "",
      "type": "Robot",
      "cbroker":"localhost:1026"
 }]
}' 'http://localhost:4041/iot/services'
```

#### Step 3: connect your sensor to the client

```
(bin/iotagent-lwm2m-client.js)

Object Creation:
LWM2M-Client> create /7392/0
Battery attribute:
LWM2M-Client> set /7392/0 1 89
Message Attribute:
LWM2M-Client> set /7392/0 2 "First robot here"
Position attribute:
LWM2M-Client> set /7392/0 3 "[0,0]
```

#### Step 4: connect with the server

```
LWM2M-Client> connect localhost 5684 robot1 /
```

#### Step 5: Update attributes

```
set /7392/0 1 67
```

#### Step 6: Query to Orion to see updated attributes

```
    curl -X POST http://localhost:1026/v1/queryContext -s -S 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'fiware-service: Factory' 
--header 'fiware-servicepath: /robots' \
-d '
{
   "entities": [
       {
           "type": "Robot",
           "isPattern": "false",
           "id": "Robot:robot1"
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I have done all the steps stated above and all is well to completion. The scenario I have is: Got an agent on my dataCollectionUnit (system) that gather data from sensors and store in sqliteDB. Now I deployed lwm2m client (wakaama) on same system, that I want to gather sensorData and forward to IDAS (on remote server) for final delivery to OrionCB. LWM2M client registers itself (auto, can confirm from server logs) with IDAS (after running client -4 -h {serverIP} -p {PORT}. How do I make the LWM2M client send the data to Orion? Is it auto (the way it registers) or I need do some configurations.

Comment: For your question, did you do step5 & step6 ?

Comment: Hi Fernando, yes sure I did.

Comment: So its nice, you response yourself ! From steps before comments, (step 5 )  it sends data to Orion. In steps 6 you can get response from Orion.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your feedback. But what is the use of Node.js above please, it seems we haven't use it here.

Comment: OMG! It was running, now I run into issues with curl:

{
    "message": "Request error connecting to the Context Broker: {\"code\":\"400\",\"reasonPhrase\":\"Bad Request\",\"details\":\"JSON Parse Error: unknown field: /contextRegistrations/contextRegistration/attributes/attribute/isDomain\"}",
    "name": "BAD_REQUEST"
}

Comment: Hi this error is cause your json is malformed. You can check your payload json here https://jsonlint.com/