# Fiware Lightweight M2M agent: how to send measures from devices

Tags: fiware, agent, coap, lwm2m

I am investigating how to use the Fiware's Lightweight M2M agent.

I read: https://fiware-iotagent-lwm2m.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deviceProvisioning/index.html  and this other helped so much: [Setting up LWM2M device communicates with IDAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330498/setting-up-lwm2m-device-communicates-with-idas)

But I didn't find how is the message's coap format waited, and where fiware-service and fiware-service-path are placed.
I get with the Lightweight M2M client I can test the client (but it is a kind of blackbox), and I would like understand how is the format for develop my own client/device.

Comment: The CoAP protocol just _transports_ LwM2M requests. In order to create a client also a knowledge of the latter is required. Would an explanation of the CoAP protocol only answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is more specific than the coap protocol. It is about how the fiware agent works. For me, its documentation is not clear. We weren't able to get how to send fiware-service and fiware-service-path trough this agent... so we made our own solution.

Comment: Mine was a comment, not an answer. ;) Your question is strange because LwM2M an the underlying coap ar both standards, so every client must work with every server (OMA used to organize meeting with different vendors in order to test interoperativity. I attended one). So, just to understand: are you asking info about coap protocol in order to develop your client (how you state in your question) or you need help to setup Fiware agent? In this case, what have you tried and what messages do you get?

Comment: Does your client compleye the bootstrap? Is your client able to register to the server? If yes, do you client presemt the object/resources list you expect? Are you able to query/update them from the server?

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMA_LWM2M)
LwM2M is specified by the [OMA](https://omaspecworks.org/what-is-oma-specworks/iot/lightweight-m2m-lwm2m/). It offers a resource-model and supports two encoding modes TLV and CBOR (at least, the newer spec).